# Making an image go behind another

Tags: html, css, image

Currently I have this:

```
<img src=assets/img/Guild/0000$logo/$logoColor.png class=\"avatar img-responsive\" style=\"margin: 0 auto;\">
<img src=assets/img/Guild/0000$logoBG/$logoBGColor.png class=\"avatar img-responsive\" style=\"margin: 0 auto;\">
```

[Visual Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3giF.png)

So the first one is a logo (in the example, a butterfly), and the second one is it's background(the green borders.) Currently it shows the logo on top and the background a space below it, but I'd like it to show the logo on top of the background (butterfly on top of the green borders.) Help?

Comment: Show some code so that we can see  where is the problem.

Comment: made a mistake, its added now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the position absolute to make them go over eachother, then add a z-index to indicate which one should be on top

```
  <img src=assets/img/Guild/0000$logo/$logoColor.png class=\"avatar img-responsive\" style=\"margin: 0 auto; position: absolute; z-index: 10;\">
  <img src=assets/img/Guild/0000$logoBG/$logoBGColor.png class=\"avatar img-responsive\" style=\"margin: 0 auto; position: absolute; z-index: -1;\">
```

Comment: Okay that works sorta, is there a way to make them centered because this seems to override <center></center> and makes it go to the furthest left it can.

Comment: You can use margins to put it in the right place,
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp 
if you want to learn about margins